# 16 Pin IDC to 40 Pin with different pinouts

Tags: ribbon-cable

I'm trying to connect a 16 pin led panel to a raspberry pi with more permanence than jumper cables.  Is it possible to build a cable with IDC on both sides if the pinouts are different?  Doesn't have to be a flat ribbon cable.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible.

It may help to carefully disassemble the connector to expose the individual IDC contacts. Then, you can "punch down" individual wires onto their contacts, eliminating the need to try to keep 16 wires all lined up at once when trying to crimp it in the usual way.